# Word or phrase for sharing content that was written by you but you don't want it to look as publicity

Tags: phrase-requests

Let's say I write a StackOverflow answer with a solution to a code problem. And someone I know runs into this problem, so I want to share the link to my answer.

What is the word or phrase to express that i'm sharing this to genuinely help him/her, not to get upvotes or publicity?

EDIT: i'm looking for something like this: "not trying to brag, but this post of mine might help you".

Answer (score 1):

You could always include the word *feel* when you share the link.  Using this in a statement tends to be interpreted as one being genuine to the cause.

> "I feel this article I wrote a while ago may complement your search for answers."

Answer (score 0):

"This might help" could be enough, since "might" mitigates the fact that you accept that it might not. You cannot completely avoid the possibility that people misinterpret a good deed.
Won't the attribution be automatically clear in the link, so you won't have to double stress your involvement?